APA Style in Biblatex
Does Biblatex not support the APA citation style anymore?
main.tex:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[natbib=true,backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\citet{Smith2024} says x.

\printbibliography

\end{document}

references.bib:
@article{Smith2024,
    author      = {John Smith},
    title       = {{Some Paper}},
    journal     = {Some Journal},
    year        = {2024},
    volume      = {1},
    number      = {1},
    pages       = {1-20}
}

This throws the error Package biblatex: Style 'apa' not found.
There are a bunch of examples online that use biblatex with style=apa. But when I try to use it, it runs into the error. It does not work with backend=bibtex either.
I know that there are packages built on Biblatex that focus on individual styles, like biblatex-apa or biblatex-chicago. Yet, as far as I am concerned, Biblatex itself supports APA natively.
I use the current versions of TexLive 2024 and Biblatex in VS Code with LaTeX Workshop.

Welcome to TeX.SE. I also use TeXLive2024 -- actually, its identical-twin sibling, MacTeX2024 -- and I experience no problem executing your code successfully, i.e.,  the apa style gets applied without a hiccup. (The log file reports biblatex 2024/03/21 v3.20 and 2023/03/20 v9.17 APA biblatex style data model.) When did you last update your TeX distribution?

apa is not one of the basic styles of biblatex. So if you are not using a full installation of TeX Live but a smaller scheme, you need to also install TeX Live package biblatex-apa.

Thanks for your answers. I have been trying to fix this for hours. I thought APA was supported natively. After installing biblatex-apa, the code now works, even without explicitly loading it in the project. Thanks.

I’m voting to close this question because the OP's issue was caused by an undisclosed condition -- that the OP's TeX distribution lacked many relevant packages, including biblatex-apa -- that was solved by installing the previously-not-installed packages.

I see the classic Stack Exchange censorship is kicking in. I did not lack many relevant packages. I lacked one. And this discussion is really helpful to fellow TeX users.

Rather than close this question, here's an answer that also clears up some misconceptions in the question.
Generally, biblatex styles are loaded simply using the style=... key when loading biblatex. This does not mean that the style is built-in to biblatex, but simply that there are .bbx and cbx files that implement the style somewhere in the texmf tree. Usually contributed styles are contributed with the name biblatex-<style>, so that their documentation can be found.  This means that they need to be installed just like any other package if not already installed. But usually, (although there are some exceptions) the style is never called using a \usepackage{biblatex-<style>} command, but is just loaded with style=... in the options of biblatex itself.
Because of this, if you don't have a full TeXLive installation, then you may need to install the relevant biblatex-<style> package in order to use that style with biblatex.  The apa style is one such style. If not installed, it is installed under the name biblatex-apa, which will also be the name that you can find its documentation under, but it is loaded simply with style=apa when loading biblatex.
